# Is the Turn Undead really usable only once a day at level 1 through 5?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, undead

I was re-reading the Cleric **Channel Divinity** section of the PHB on page 58 and now I see that the **Turn Undead** ability can only be used once per day.

In the old days, there was no limit and I have to say that I played it that way in my realm (so my cleric player used it at will!) With the saving throw, undeads are not unlikely to not be turned anyway and as soon as you hit them, they wake up out of their fright... So it did not make much difference.

Is that correct that it can only be used once? And if one uses the **Turn Undead** ability, that eats up that "slot" and one cannot use another feature such as the **Preserve Life** (p. 60, *Life Domain*).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The *Channel Divinity* feature states that it can be used up to one time **between short or long rests**. That goes for whatever you use it for, be it *Turn Undead* or whatever your Domain gives you. It also states in the last few sentences that at 6th level a Cleric can use it twice between rests, and at 18th they can use it up to three times.

The key difference is the specificity in saying *rests* as well as including short rests. Some things in D&D 5e check for the next dawn, and some things reset only after a long rest, but this comes back more often.